# Мои крон задачи не работают внутри докера

Tags: python, docker, flask, crontab

```
@crontab.job(minute="*")
def live_matches():
    from application import container

    task_creator = container.task_creator()
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    matches = LiveMatchUpdaterCron(app, task_creator)
    matches.live_match_updater()
```

В данном коде вызывается другая функция, но эта функция внутри докера не запускается

```
FROM python:3.10.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron curl


EXPOSE 8084

COPY . .
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Мой докер файл

Comment: @crontab это не крон

Comment: Тогда я ошибаюсь, но это не работает